# adding a '\\server\printer' type printer after spooler service restart takes 45 seconds, every time

Tags: networking, printing, windows-10, rpc, windows-server-2016

Adding a windows shared printer (like \\server\printer) after a spooler service restart (or computer reboot), takes about 45 seconds every single time.  This is even after the driver is downloaded.  Server is Windows 2016.  Client can be Windows 7 or Windows 10.  I've tried process monitor, but still can't figure it out.  To reproduce:

```
# as admin (powershell)
restart-service spooler

# as regular user
date
add-printer -connectionname \\server\printer
date


Wednesday, May 2, 2018 10:39:08 AM
Wednesday, May 2, 2018 10:39:51 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the server print spooler service (spoolsv) uses rpc which listens on a dynamic port (49152-65535), and some kind of firewall was blocking it.  After a timeout, printing will shift to port 135.